# Where can I find charitable donation tax credit rates for each provinces and territories in Canada?

Tags: canada, tax-deduction

The only official source I found was this one and it's from 2017...

https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/charities-giving/giving-charity-information-donors/claiming-charitable-tax-credits/charitable-donation-tax-credit-rates.html

Comment: I think you will find that the page has not been modified since 2017 because the rates haven't changed since 2017.

Comment: Hello, sorry for not responding for so long... it seems that it did change though https://www.taxtips.ca/filing/donations/tax-credit-rates-2023.htm